# FLushing tankless water heater without hot water shutoff

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, tankless, maintenance

I have a Bradford White RTG-K-199N1 tankless gas water heater. It has hot and cold water connections on top, and 2 flush valves at the bottom. I wanted to do a descaling flush, and the manual specifies that both the cold water supply and hot water pipes have to be shut off with a valve before starting the flush. My install only has a shut off on the cold supply, but not on the hot side. Is it still possible to flush, if I connect a submersible pump in a bucket of vinegar to the two bottom flush valves, and only close the cold water supply? I was thinking that as long as I keep the hot water taps in the house closed, the vinegar will only circulate inside the water heater, and not go into the pipes of the house. Is that true?

The copper hot water pipe is 3/4", see picture. [image: Hot water connection without shut off valve]
[image: Overview of tankless heater]
[image: Drain plugs on bottom of heater]

Thanks

Comment: Don't hire that plumber again.

Comment: I agree, unfortunately it was this way when we bought the house.

Comment: Shut off the house main valve, install new valve on hot?

Comment: Interesting that the OP's WH has flush valves separate from the two water connections (cold in, heated out). For our 15 yo Bosch Aquastar I had to get a pair of external valves each of which shuts off the water and opens the connection to the flushing port.

Comment: Something sounds wrong here. If you would put a shutoff valve on the hot water side would n't it be past the temp relief valve? Meaning the temp relief valve would be exposed to the vinegar. My hot water out valve incorates a port for the temp relif valve so it is not exposed to vinegar in descaling. Is it possible that the hot out flushing valve of the water heater incorporates a shutoff valve? Is it clear exactly what the function of those "flushing" connections at the bottom is?

Comment: @JimStewart I added a couple of pics. Manuals shows hot water shut off valve after the TPR, so it would be exposed to vinegar. Manual is also very specific about using only bottom ports for flushing.

Comment: So the drain/flushing ports have integral shutoff valves (engagable by large flat-blade screwdriver) but the output hot connection does not?! Are you sure there is no similar shutoff on that hot output fitting? what about under the cover?

Comment: You could try to find out from Brdford White whether you need a shutoff valve on the output side to perform a descaling of the heat exchanger. It could be that as long as no hot water valves are open that there would be no significant entry of vinegar into the hot water distribution lines. Then after the vinegar drains out you could open a hot water tap and some water would drain down through the heat exchanger and rinse out  the exchanger.